# Hibernate Connection Pool vs DataSource Connection Pool

Tags: connection-pooling

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.jdbcurl}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.c3po.max_size=20
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hi guys, I have above set up for my application. We use DBCP connection pool. However, We have also set c3po properties in my hibernate SessionFactory.

My observation from the log suggests that DBCP overwrite the C3P0 properties in hibernate.

In this situation, is c3p0 property complete redundant? If yes, does it take up unnecessary resources in any way?

Thanks.